# I get an error when trying to use the 'Name' function in the Control class in vb.net (as a code-behind to a APS.net form)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to be able to pull data from 6 text boxes with identical names (other than a number at the end) in a for loop

here is the error:

```
'Name' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.
```

here is the code:

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    For Each c As Control In Controls
        If c.Name = "txtBox" & i Then
            intValue(i) = Convert.ToInt32(c.Text)
        End If
    Next
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Name is not in fact a member of System.Web.UI.Control.
You probably have an instance of a derived class, in which case you will need to cast to the correct class before calling Name or Text.

With more context, we could give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Context provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    For Each c As TextBox In Controls.OfType(of TextBox)()
        If c.Name = "txtBox" & i Then
            intValue(i) = Convert.ToInt32(c.Text)
        End If
    Next
  Next i
```

Comment: 'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection'.

Comment: @Glenncito make sure you have `Imports System.Linq`